# How do I stop a comma being added in database field when using CONCAT_WS if column is empty

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to add value in database as 1,2,3 but when database contain null value it adds like ,1,2,3 my query as How to avoid , added when field is null.

```
 DB::table('table_user_create_activity')
               ->where(['activity_id'=>$query_get_activity->activity_id])
              ->update(['accepted_join_id'=>DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(',', ifnull(accepted_join_id,''),".$get_user_id.')')]);
```

Comment: Why not wrap the `ifnull` around or add some kind of `CASE`? Are you sure that `CONCAT_WS` on an empty column really outputs a single `,`?

Comment: If database contain null value and i want to save new value , then it first add , and then value. Plz change query

Comment: Better thing would be to stop storing comma separated values. Dont do this; normalize the DB. Thanks me later :)
Read: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya actually each time user_id is appended with old user_id